# Do you have a common base class for Hibernate entities?

Tags: java, hibernate, entities, base-class

Do you have a common base class for Hibernate entities, i.e. a MappedSuperclass with id, version and other common properties? Are there any drawbacks?

Example:

```
@MappedSuperclass()
public class BaseEntity {

    private Long id;
    private Long version;
    ...

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Long getId() {return id;}

    public void setId(Long id) {this.id = id;}

    @Version
    public Long getVersion() {return version;}
    ...

    // Common properties
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    public Date creationDate() {return creationDate;}
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Customer extends BaseEntity {
    private String customerName;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works fine for us. As well as the ID and creation date, we also have a modified date. We also have an intermediate *TaggedBaseEntity* that implements a *Taggable* interface, because some of our web application's entities have tags, like questions on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 5):

The one that I use is primarily to implement hashCode() and equals().  I also added a method to pretty print the entity.  In response to DR above, most of this can be overridden, but in my implementation you are stuck with an ID of type Long.

```
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {

    public abstract Long getId();
    public abstract void setId(Long id);

    /**
     * @see java.lang.Object#hashCode()
     */
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((getId() == null) ? 0 : getId().hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    /**
     * @see java.lang.Object#equals(Object)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        BaseEntity other = (BaseEntity) obj;
        if (getId() == null) {
            if (other.getId() != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!getId().equals(other.getId()))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @see java.lang.Object#toString()
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringBuilder(getClass().getSimpleName()).append(":").append(getId()).toString();
    }

    /**
     * Prints complete information by calling all public getters on the entity.
     */
    public String print() {

        final String EQUALS = "=";
        final String DELIMITER = ", ";
        final String ENTITY_FORMAT = "(id={0})";

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("{");

        PropertyDescriptor[] properties = PropertyUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(this);
        PropertyDescriptor property = null;
        int i = 0;
        while ( i < properties.length) {

            property = properties[i];
            sb.append(property.getName());
            sb.append(EQUALS);

            try {
                Object value = PropertyUtils.getProperty(this, property.getName());
                if (value instanceof BaseEntity) {
                    BaseEntity entityValue = (BaseEntity) value;
                    String objectValueString = MessageFormat.format(ENTITY_FORMAT, entityValue.getId());
                    sb.append(objectValueString);
                } else {
                    sb.append(value);
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                // do nothing
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                // do nothing
            } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                // do nothing
            }

            i++;
            if (i < properties.length) {
                sb.append(DELIMITER);
            }
        }

        sb.append("}");

        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Excuse me, but why are you using a while loop for what seems to fit more in a for loop?

Comment: Yes, I could have done something like:

for (i = 0; i < properties.length; i++) {

but if you look at the bottom, after the i++, I use i after it has been incremented.

Perhaps there is another way, but this is perfectly readable.

Comment: It's been a while since this question, but nevertheless, there's a bug in the above equals() method, which can create problems with proxies: instead of getClass() != obj.getClass() use either isAssignableFrom() or !(obj instanceof BaseEntity)

Comment: We've been using the lombok @EqualsAndHashCode annotation on our entities. This has been much less error prone than writing them ourselves.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't hesitate to use a common base class, after all that's the point of O/R mapping.

I use common base classes, too, but only if the entities share at least some common properties. I won't use it, if the ID is the only common property. Until now I did not encounter any problems.

Answer (score 0):

It works well for me too.

Notice that you can also in this entity add some event listeners / interceptors like the Hibernate Envers one or any custom one according to your need so that you can:
- Track all modifications
- Know which user made the last modification
- Update automatically the last modification
- Set automatically the first insertion date
And ther stuff like that...

Answer (score -1):

You can find some samples here

http://blogsprajeesh.blogspot.com/2010/01/nhibernate-defining-mappings-part-4.html