# How to avoid duplicate code in JPA Entity

Tags: java, jpa, model

I have 2 Object A and B, which have same attributes, but different table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

    @Id
    private Integer id;
    ...
}
```

it will cause duplicate code because every attributes are same.
What is best practice to do this kind of problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do you have a common base class for Hibernate entities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156689/do-you-have-a-common-base-class-for-hibernate-entities)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd create a `@MappedSupperclass` for this, and extend from it. It would look like this

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Common {
    @Id
    private Integer id;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A extends Common {
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B extends Common {
    ...
}
```

This doesn't create an entity hierarchy, but only moves common entity attributes in a super class. Often used for `id`, `version`, `createdBy` etc.

Comment: Just wondering if this is not a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/156689/do-you-have-a-common-base-class-for-hibernate-entities ...